# JIRA REST API Oauth dance cannot be implemented with consumer key

Tags: rest, oauth, jira

I am trying to call the JIRA REST API and get a request token. I have defined an application link in JIRA with consumer key and public key. But when I am trying to request the request-token with the following url

`http://localhost:8080//plugins/servlet/oauth/request-token?oauth_consumer_key=consumerKey` (which was used in creating the application link)

I am getting the following response

oauth_problem=consumer_key_unknown

How to get rid of this?

Comment: Did you create the application link for localhost? When creating link,the consumer key should be something like application name and the public key is encoded rsa-sha1 public key. Was the link successfully created?

Answer (score -2):

This link would be handy if you are using python.
https://bitbucket.org/atlassian_tutorial/atlassian-oauth-examples/src/d625161454d1ca97b4515c6147b093fac9a68f7e/python/app.py?at=default

Also use python `centrifi` package to get pass sslHandShakeError. ( atlassian root certificate seems to be not from known one )